# Extract Data Label from Excel Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Experts,

I'm trying to extract the data labels from an auto-generated excel chart. I have a decent amount of VBA experience, but unfortunately very little with charts. From my understand of researching the topic there is a way to iterate through all items on the chart to find those that have data labels.

**Input:**
-Chart Sheet, ex "Step 0.2"
-Scatterplot with straight lines.

**Output:** 
-Data labels from chart to separate sheet
-Location, ex "Main"

An attempt:

```
Option Explicit

'Loop through chart to find data labels
Sub FindDataLabels()

    'Define worksheet and chart
    Dim mainPage As Worksheet
    Dim TestChart As chart

    Set mainPage = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    Set TestChart = Charts("Step 0.2")

    'Extract data points from chart for analysis
    Dim line1 As SeriesCollection
    Set line1 = TestChart.SeriesCollection

    Dim dataPoints As Double
    dataPoints = line1.Count
Debug.Print "datapoints: "; dataPoints

    Dim LabelsArray(2) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To dataPoints
        If line1(i).HasDataLabels Then

                Debug.Print "data label: "; line1(i).DataLabels.Text

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's code to extract data label values from an Excel Chart**

Prints out values to Immediate Window

```
Dim datapoint As Point

For Each datapoint In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points

    'Extract data labels
    If datapoint.HasDataLabel Then Debug.Print datapoint.DataLabel.Text

Next
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much.